# joining string for a counter in python dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, join, pandas-groupby

I have read a `csv` which has two columns: `date`, and `tweet`. The file is read in a `df`,

```
    df= pd.read_csv(
    "data/101.csv",
    usecols=["date", "tweet"]
    .rename(
    columns={
    "date": "date",
    "tweet": "tweet",
    }
    ).set_index("date")
    df['count']=df.groupby('date').size()
    df
```

Now, my `df` looks like the following:

```
|   date   |                              tweet                               |
| -------- | ---------------------------------------------------------------- |
|2020-03-19|    These are desperate times ppl. My son couldnÃ¢â‚¬â„¢t possibly wait for his piece to be cut. pic.twitter.com/zbsysMXpgZ
|2020-03-19|    Aweeee. My bby says hello. pic.twitter.com/aQOW0AtzyX
|2020-03-19|    You sure do!!! pic.twitter.com/oed7At9ZIX
|2020-03-18|    Seriously. Fuck you savages. pic.twitter.com/gG4vDKhZ3W
|2020-03-17|    Harley wants out as well pic.twitter.com/Vkf7Qh6vPz
|2020-03-17|    I posted a sign that said Be A Nice Human on #mercari & this was some lunatics response. @mercari_app nice ppl you let on your platform. pic.twitter.com/mH14t3nPRA
|2020-03-17|    New profiles keep popping up on #Mercari so ppl can sell hand sanitizer. ItÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s ridiculous. Stop it. #pricegouging @CDC_eHealth @mercari_app pic.twitter.com/1OFAcqpive
|2020-03-17|    Heath Ledger pic.twitter.com/YmJWQGalZL
|2020-03-16|    Well, this is strange. But oddly accurate. pic.twitter.com/DZc9jwSolJ
```

What I wanna get is to combine all the `tweet` for a given `date` in a single row (as calculated in `count` column). as in the table above, first three rows be combined in a single row with single instance of date "2020-03-19", count "3" and of first three tweets(strings) in a single cell of tweet column. this is done by looking at the `df['count']` for each specific `df['date']`. , and similarly, 4 rows be combined for "2020-03-17" in a single row. with a single count value "4" and combined all four corresponding tweets.

**What I have tried is:**

```
    #df['count']=df.groupby('date').size()
    count=3 # here, defined for convention. must be taken from df['count'] for each date
    df['combined_tweets'] = "".join(str(tweet),c for tweet,c in df['tweet'],count)
```

But I got

> SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized.

I also tried:

```
    count=3
    for c in count:
    for t in df['tweet']:
    df['combined_tweets'] += str(t)
    print(df['combined_tweets'])
```

And this time I got:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

And when I simply write without count:

```
    df['tweet_string'] = " ".join(tweet for tweet in df["tweet"])
    df['tweet_string']
```

It gives:

```
|0|These are desperate times ppl. My son couldnÃ¢...
|1|These are desperate times ppl. My son couldnÃ¢...
|2|These are desperate times ppl. My son couldnÃ¢...
|3|These are desperate times ppl. My son couldnÃ¢...
|4|These are desperate times ppl. My son couldnÃ¢...
...
...
...
```

And even when:

```
    tweet_string = " ".join(tweet for tweet in df["tweet"])
    tweet_string
```

Then it gives:

> 'These are desperate times ppl. My son couldnÃ¢â‚¬â„¢t possibly wait for his piece to be cut. pic.twitter.com/zbsysMXpgZ Aweeee. My bby says hello. pic.twitter.com/aQOW0AtzyX You sure do!!! pic.twitter.com/oed7At9ZIX HeÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s ridiculous This is so racist. ItÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s a virus. It could have started anywhere. [https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/1240391871026864130Ã‚Â\xa0Ã¢â‚¬Â¦](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/1240391871026864130%C3%83%E2%80%9A%C3%82%5Cxa0%C3%83%C2%A2%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC%C3%82%C2%A6) Seriously. Fuck you savages. pic.twitter.com/gG4vDKhZ3W Try living here. ItÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s even harder. Thank you for saying what I have always felt. Stay safeÃ°Å¸â„¢â€š I would go with aluminum because of Primus & for the....

**What I actually need is:**

```
|   date   |count|                                  combined_tweets                                     |
| -------- | --- | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
|2020-03-19|  3  |  These are desperate times ppl. My son couldnÃ¢â‚¬â„¢t possibly wait for his piece to be cut. pic.twitter.com/zbsysMXpgZ Aweeee. My bby says hello. pic.twitter.com/aQOW0AtzyX You sure do!!! pic.twitter.com/oed7At9ZIX
|2020-03-18|  1  |  Seriously. Fuck you savages. pic.twitter.com/gG4vDKhZ3W
|2020-03-17|  4  |  Harley wants out as well pic.twitter.com/Vkf7Qh6vPz I posted a sign that said Be A Nice Human on #mercari & this was some lunatics response. @mercari_app nice ppl you let on your platform. pic.twitter.com/mH14t3nPRA New profiles keep popping up on #Mercari so ppl can sell hand sanitizer. ItÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s ridiculous. Stop it. #pricegouging @CDC_eHealth @mercari_app pic.twitter.com/1OFAcqpive Heath Ledger pic.twitter.com/YmJWQGalZL
|2020-03-16|  1  |  Well, this is strange. But oddly accurate. pic.twitter.com/DZc9jwSolJ
```

What should I try for ?

Answer (score 0):

```
I also tried:


count=3
for c in count:
for t in df['tweet']:
df['combined_tweets'] += str(t)
print(df['combined_tweets'])

And this time I got:

    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Here you can't do a for loop straigth from an integer, you need to use `range` function to iterate over a numeric index, something like this

```
count=3
for c in range(0,count):
  for t in df['tweet']:
    df['combined_tweets'] += str(t)
    print(df['combined_tweets'])
```

Comment: yeah, but as I mentioned already that `count` here is defined for convention. but i have to take its value from df['count']. as follows: 

```

for c in range(0,df['count']):
    for t in df['tweet']:
        df['combined_tweets'] += str(t)

print(df['combined_tweets'])

```

and now, i got the error: 

> 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I think thats because you are taking the whole column of df['count']. Remember that range funciton only takes as input integer values. You need to take the integer value of the count of that date and iterate over that

Comment: then how do i get that integer value from df['count'] to be used in loop?

Comment: By iterating over that dataframe as well, something like
for count in df['count']:
  for c in range(0,count):
    for t in df['tweet']:
      df['combined_tweets'] += str(t)
      print(df['combined_tweets'])